# How to save RegIniFile as IniFile in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, registry, ini, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My Win32 application uses a registry key utilizing TRegIniFile like this:

```
  MyData:=TRegIniFile.Create('\Software\MyApp');
```

The registry key has subkeys and values.

How can I export all the data as INI file utilizing TIniFile?

Comment: Load all of your data into a `TIniFile` or a `TMemIniFile`, and then save it.

Comment: How to load it?

Comment: Well, you presumably know what keys and values you want to work with. You already have code to read the values that have meaning.

Comment: Despite its name, `TRegIniFile` has no functionality to write to an INI file (neither does `TRegistryIniFile`, either).  You are going to have to manually read sections and values from `TRegIniFile` (likely with a recursive function), copying them to a `T(Mem)IniFile`, and then you can save that `T(Mem)IniFile` to an INI file.